# C++ Program doesn't require admin/UAC after copying

Tags: c++, file, compilation, manifest, runas

This is my first post, I've only recently started learning C++, the program that I've made requires admin permissions to run, and It works fine on my computer, but if I copy it on someone else's computer, it seems like the manifest info gets corrupted or something, and it no longer requires Admin/UAC. I'm using 
 visual studio to compile my code. Here are manifest file properties of my program while compiling:

Enable User Account Control(UAC): Yes

UAC Execution level:requireAdministrator

UAC Bypass UI Protetion:No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has nothing with c++ stuff but the OS it was copied into
cross-check copying it to another OS, will it issue the same exact problem
likely is the ACL of directory on which it's copied, tell it back.

Comment: I just created a virtual machine to test this, and it behaves exactly the same... Somehow the manifest file loses it's information :(

Comment: not virtual. cross check test it on real OS, very most likely dir.'s ACL of the copy target, set it to 100% full perm and see what the different is..